# Search Index for user articles

Tags: python, search, indexing, flask

I am building a Note Making application where users can create notes, add photos, tag and share it with friends.
I am using python flask framework for building the tool.

I want to provide a feature wherein user can search through their notes.
How do I go about building the index, are there any libraries which can do this quickly ?

I am using MongoDB as a backend DB

Comment: There's plenty to choose from.  How do you want to handle the backend?  mysql, postgresql, sqlite, csv, nosql, some custom filetype?

Comment: I am using MongoDB as backend DB

Comment: I've never used them, but you could take a look at these. They might come in handy. Flask-PyMongo: https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and MongoKit: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/mongokit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Flask-WhooshAlchemy.

Flask-WhooshAlchemy is a Flask extension that integrates the text-search functionality of Whoosh with the ORM of SQLAlchemy for use in Flask applications.

**Install**

```
pip install flask_whooshalchemy
```

**Quickstart**

```
import flask.ext.whooshalchemy

# set the location for the whoosh index
app.config['WHOOSH_BASE'] = 'path/to/whoosh/base'


class BlogPost(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'blogpost'
  __searchable__ = ['title', 'content']  # these fields will be indexed by whoosh

  id = app.db.Column(app.db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = app.db.Column(app.db.Text)
  content = app.db.Column(app.db.Text)
  created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

  def __repr__(self):
     return '{0}(title={1})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.title)
```

**Create a post**

```
db.session.add(
    BlogPost(title='My cool title', content='This is the first post.')
); db.session.commit()
```

**Text searching**

```
results = BlogPost.query.whoosh_search('cool')
```

**We can limit results:**

```
# get 2 best results:
results = BlogPost.query.whoosh_search('cool', limit=2)
```

source: [Flask-WhooshAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/)

Comment: Flask-WhooshAlchemy is a Flask extension that integrates the text-search functionality of Whoosh with the **ORM** of **SQLAlchemy** for use in Flask applications. Based on given description I would say not...